# How do I update a compiler?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, .net-5, c#-9.0

So, I just installed net5 on this pc. It is fresh new and when I went to PowerShell and run the `csc -langversion:?` command to check which versions of C# it supports I receive this message:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1038.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer v
ersions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

warning CS2008: Nenhum arquivo de origem especificado
error CS1617: Opção '?' inválida para /langversion; deve ser ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 ou Default
```

Not only the compiler doesn't support C# 9.0 and it doesn't show the supposed message it was supposed to which is something like this:

```
default
1
2
3
4
5
6
7.0
7.1
7.2
7.3
8.0
9.0 (default)
latestmajor
preview
latest
```

As my nick suggests I'm pretty new to programming and stuff, so can anyone help me?

Comment: Try installing latest version of .NET Framework ([develper back from here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48) or via Visual Studio).

Comment: Just finished to update my windows to the latest version (21h1 if I'm not mistaken) so I can download .Net Framework 4.8 (latest version of .Net framework) but I keep getting the same message

Comment: Did you install the [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) or did you just install the runtime? I think you will need the SDK to get all the supported the languages.

Comment: Ya, got the sdk installed :

`PS C:\Users\Lucas Souza> dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`

Answer (score 2):

You say you installed .NET 5. But then you used the `csc` command which is *not* part of .NET 5. The output of the command even says that you are using `.NET Framework`, which is *not* .NET 5.

.NET 5 is a different thing than .NET Framework.

All .NET 5 command are invoked using `dotnet`.

`dotnet --info` will tell you if the .NET 5.0 SDK is installed. If you have the .NET 5 SDK, [it will support C#, even if you can't directly query the language version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults).

Comment: But ya, I got .NET 5 installed see:

`.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.301 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]`

It returns me a lot of info when I use `dotnet --info` so I just pasted the important part. Does that means I'm safe to use C# 9.0 even if the compiler says it supports only C# 5.0 and bellow?

Comment: The `csc` compiler that you are running manually is a different compiler than the one included with .NET 5. The `csc` compiler will not support C# 9. The .NET 5 compiler (which you use via `dotnet build` or `dotnet run`) will support C# 9.

Comment: So for clarification: It is important to change the csc compiler for a version that supports C# 9? And if it does, how do I do it? Sorry for all the trouble I'm cause, I just love programming but since I'm new to the scene I just have to rely on people more experience than me. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Eh, no worries. You should use the  `dotnet` commands (like `dotnet build`) to build your code. Don't use `csc`, that will use the older compiler that doesn't support C# 9. If you are following a guide/tutorial that tells you to use `csc`, that document is out of date and wont work with .NET 5.